# How to created a model polycrystalline

Tags: modeling

I created a model polycrystalline from a cube, I use Cell Fracture for that, so the problem I always find is that there are intersections of the faces and overhang face, this model then export in STL format, can you help me solve these problems in cell fracture..
[image]

Model polycrystalline
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you want to join the faces back together, you can either select both faces, and press **F** in edit mode, or you can select the vertices around the faces and press **F**.

Comment: If there are too many faces that do not stick together, see these images, as if three lines appear between two pieces.